# QTP: Parameterize a Database Checkpoint

Tags: automation, automated-tests, qtp

I have a database checkpoint in QTP (HP QuickTest Pro); this checkpoint works if I pass it a static query, but I need to be able to pass in parameters or build the query programatically. I also know how to query the database programatically from QTP, but don't see a way to create a checkpoint based on its results.

Specifically, I want to cause a FAIL if the returned RecordCount = 0, and PASS if >= 1. I'm a Developer, not a Tester; and the [QTP forums](http://www.learnqtp.com/forums/how-to-variable-checkpoint-t-1559.html) aren't responding - Help me SO!

This is the code I tried -- which works but lacks a Checkpoint:

```
Dim con, rs,strSQL, Param1, Param2
Param1 = DataTable("B", dtGlobalSheet)
Param2 = DataTable("A", dtGlobalSheet)
Set con=Createobject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs=Createobject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.CursorLocation = 3
rs.CursorType =3
connSTR= "Driver={SQL Server};Server=vsql0001;Database=DB0001;Dsn=myRegistryName"
con.open connSTR
strSQL= "select Field1, Field2 from dbo.Table1 where Field1 in (select Field1 from     dbo.Table2 where Param2 like '%"+Param2+"%' and active = 1) and (Field2     = '"+Param1+"' or Field2 like '"+Param1+" %' or Field2 like '%*"+Param1+"' or Field2     like '%*"+Param1+"*%')"
rs.open strSQL, con
msgbox rs.recordcount   ' want the CP to go here
rs.close
con.close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.  I give it the static query and change it before it evaluates.

```
strSQL= "select [...]"
DbTable("DbTable").SetTOProperty "Source", strSQL
DbTable("DbTable").Check CheckPoint("DbTable")
```